# Move values from DataFrame json column into Dataframe rows

Tags: python, json, pandas

Can't resolve such a problem.
I have a JSON file, with some nested dicts in its column
So I load JSON into Dataframe with:

```
df2=pd.read_json(filename)
```

And now a I have Dataframe with main column - SKU and another column, which contains a dict like:

```
"other_stores": 
{"addrcode1": {"address": "Address1", "price_current": 990.0, "in_stock_count": 1, "price_original": 990.0},
"addrcode2": {"address": "Address2", "price_current": 990.0, "in_stock_count": 1, "price_original": 990.0}}
```

with command like `apply(pd.Series)`
I can move each "addrcode1" into columns of my data frame and create a table like this:

| SKU | brand | title | addrcode1 | addrcode2 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sku1 | brand1 | title1 | {addrcode1:data} | {addrcode2:data} |

But what I'm trying to do - is to create a table like:

| SKU | brand | title | address | address_price | address_stock |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| sku1 | brand1 | title1 | address1 | address1_price | address1_stock |
| sku1 | brand1 | title1 | address2 | address2_price | address2_stock |

Sample of JSON is:

```
[
  {
    "SKU": "sampleSKU",
    "brand": "My Brand",
    "title": "My SKU title",
    "other_stores": {
      "addrcode1": {
        "address": "Address1",
        "price_current": 990,
        "in_stock_count": 1,
        "price_original": 990
      },
      "addrcode2": {
        "address": "Address2",
        "price_current": 990,
        "in_stock_count": 1,
        "price_original": 990
      }
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: have you tried [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)

Comment: Yes i have.

`df2=pd.json_normalize(df2,['other_stores'])`


 it generates error : tring indices must be integers

Comment: I have added 2 ways you can get your expected output, with json_normalize and with the method that you are already employing. do check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Using multiple df.apply(pd.Series) with df.stack()

Your "JSON" is not really in a structure that can be easily normalized. For your nested dictionary structured JSON, you can use the following:

1. Convert the list of dicts to pandas dataframe.
2. Then for the `other_stores` column, apply `pd.Series` followed by stacking the 2 addrcode1 and addrcode2,
3. Then another apply `pd.Series` to extract the columns needed
4. Finally concatenate the original dataframe with the nested one.

```
d = [{'SKU': 'sampleSKU 1',
  'brand': 'My Brand 1',
  'title': 'My SKU 1 title',
  'other_stores': {'addrcode1': {'address': 'Address1',
    'price_current': 990,
    'in_stock_count': 1,
    'price_original': 990},
   'addrcode2': {'address': 'Address2',
    'price_current': 990,
    'in_stock_count': 1,
    'price_original': 990}}}, 
    {'SKU': 'sampleSKU 2',
      'brand': 'My Brand 2',
      'title': 'My SKU 2 title',
      'other_stores': {'addrcode1': {'address': 'Address1',
        'price_current': 990,
        'in_stock_count': 1,
        'price_original': 990},
       'addrcode2': {'address': 'Address2',
        'price_current': 990,
        'in_stock_count': 1,
        'price_original': 990}}}]

df = pd.DataFrame(d)
nested = df['other_stores'].apply(pd.Series).stack().apply(pd.Series)

pd.concat([df.drop('other_stores',1), nested.reset_index(-1, drop=True)], axis=1)
```

[image]

---

#### Using pd.json_normalize() on a slighly modified JSON

If you do have control over how your JSON is structure, might I advise adding lists to store nested dicts. This allows you to utilize `pd.json_normalize` as a convenience function, with `record_path` and `meta` parameters -

```
d_fixed = [
  {
    "SKU": "sampleSKU",
    "brand": "My Brand",
    "title": "My SKU title",
    "other_stores": [{            #<---- list start
      "addrcode1": [{                #<---- nested list start
        "address": "Address1",
        "price_current": 990,
        "in_stock_count": 1,
        "price_original": 990
      }],                            #<---- nested list end
      "addrcode2": [{                #<---- nested list start
        "address": "Address2",
        "price_current": 990,
        "in_stock_count": 1,
        "price_original": 990
      }]                             #<---- nested list end
    }]                        #<---- list end
  }
]


a1 = pd.json_normalize(d_fixed, record_path = ['other_stores','addrcode1'], meta=['SKU','brand','title'])
a2 = pd.json_normalize(d_fixed, record_path = ['other_stores','addrcode2'], meta=['SKU','brand','title'])

df = pd.concat([a1,a2])
df = df[['SKU','brand','title','address','price_current','in_stock_count','price_original']]
df
```

[image]

Comment: Hello! Thank you for the great answer!
I haven't control over json, so *Using multiple df.apply(pd.Series) with df.stack()*
is my answer, although it's quite slow on large  Dataframes.  
But i think it can be useful for other people who will face the same problem

Comment: Great, glad to hear it solved your question. Do mark the answer if it did! thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use -

```
a=[
  {
    "SKU": "sampleSKU",
    "brand": "My Brand",
    "title": "My SKU title",
    "other_stores": {
      "addrcode1": {
        "address": "Address1",
        "price_current": 990,
        "in_stock_count": 1,
        "price_original": 990
      },
      "addrcode2": {
        "address": "Address2",
        "price_current": 990,
        "in_stock_count": 1,
        "price_original": 990
      }
    }
  }
]

pd.json_normalize(a)
```

**Output**

```
    SKU brand   title   other_stores.addrcode1.address  other_stores.addrcode1.price_current    other_stores.addrcode1.in_stock_count   other_stores.addrcode1.price_original   other_stores.addrcode2.address  other_stores.addrcode2.price_current    other_stores.addrcode2.in_stock_count   other_stores.addrcode2.price_original
0   sampleSKU   My Brand    My SKU title    Address1    990 1   990 Address2    990 1   990
```

**Update**

Try this example -

```
import json
# load data using Python JSON module
with open('data/simple.json','r') as f:
    data = json.loads(f.read())
    
# Flattening JSON data
pd.json_normalize(data)
```

Comment: Hi, thanks!
Look,  i use two commands:
  
    `df2=pd.read_json(filename)
    df2=pd.json_normalize(df2)`
  
Where filename - is json-file where i store JSON in the start post
if i run such commands i receive error:<br/>
if any([isinstance(x, dict) for x in y.values()] for y in data):
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: Sorry, i have tried :  
`pd.read_json(pd.json_normalize(filename))  
df2=pd.json_normalize(pd.read_json(filename))`  
And recieve tha same error. Why? 
But. If init a like you said, then i'ts ok, except one thing:  
I wanted for these two adrresses - two rows for each address with same SKU..

Comment: Yes, it worked your way. Thank you.  
Unfortunately i 've loaded .gz archive with `pd.read_json`, but with json.loads it returns error, is any way to use dp.readJson ?
and still, with your example there is one resulting row, where whold be two for each SKU